# Count processed records of a table at the runtime of a script?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script and its running and using two mysql tables for processing. Now i want to check that how many records has that script processed so far as my tables are having huge amount of data more than 90 lakhs. How can i check this at the same time when that script is running ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to impement a streaming to achieve that. You can have more details about that [here](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming). I have checked [APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) and I think this can meet your needs.